# There is no error on JQuery $.post but i cannot insert into the database the request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello i need help with inserting data into the database using a JQuery post request,i want to send the request on a on click event of an input of type 'image', there seems to be an error with my code because the request doesn't reach the ajax server file.
 Here is the HTML form `

```
 <form name="frm-survey" id="frm-survey" method="post" action="#">
  <input type="hidden" name="got-form" id="got-form">

     <div class="row">
         <ul id="survey">
             <li id="one"><input id="one" type="image" src="/survey/emojis/numbers/1.png"></li>        

         </ul>

     </div>

    <input id="que_id_increment" name="que_id_increment" type="hidden" value= "2">
   </form>`
```

Here is the JQuery script,this is the onclick event of the li>input[image],this event is with in a document.ready event

```
$("#survey li").click(function(e){
    if (the_form) {

        console.log("Form found,form submitted");

    $.post( "process.php" , 
           {
            action: "InsertQandAs",
             question:the_question, 
             answer:the_answer

           }).error(function(){
                console.log("There was an doing the insert request");

           }).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
    }

    else {

        console.log("Could not submit the form");

    }

});
```

And then here is the ajax file,which receives the 'InsertQandAs' action from the JQuery post request

```
if(class_exists('QandAs')) {

     if($action =="InsertQandAs") {

       //QandAs::insertQandA($question,$q_id,$answer);

       echo "Im here";
    }

    else {
     die("The action was not found");
   }
}

else {

die("The class QandAs does not exist");

}
```

Comment: remove the `action` part from your `<form>` or add `e.preventDefault();` inside `$("#survey li").click(function(e){`

Comment: i did the prevent default but it seems like JQuery doesnt even listen to the click event

Comment: I did this  $("#survey li").click(function(e){ console.log("Hey");},nothing was displayed when i clicked,but the form seems to be submitted when i check with PHP

Comment: do you added jquery library or not?

Comment: I did,JQuery is added beacuse,on document ready i load the <li>s using a post request as well